# Formula that returns the column reference of the last non-zero value cell in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a list of values by month for multiple users in a Google Sheet (trailing 12 months). In another column, I need to provide the column reference for the last non-zero value in that row. So, for instance, if all 12 months are non-zero, the formula returns 12, but if the last three months are zero, the formula would return 9.

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103430/formula-that-displays-the-last-non-zero-value-cell) returns the last non-zero value (so close!) - I am looking for the column reference for that value.

Comment: Have  you tried `address`, `column`, any of the lookup functions built-in functions?

Comment: Related : [Return cell reference containing closest value](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/99412/88163)

Comment: Hey this question was answered here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126612/296276